# Conflict between js codes [navbar]

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I was creating a sticky nav bar using JS, works perfectly, until i added another JS code to adapt for mobile devices, if the second one is wnabled, the bar doesnt stick to the top, but if disabled, works fine.

**JS#1**(sticky navbar)

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("mynavbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
```

**JS#2**(open/close navbar menu in mobiles)

```
function myFunction() {

    var x = document.getElementsById("mynavbar");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += "responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 functions named `myFunction`. The second one is going to override your first one, causing the sticky class to never get added/removed. Use different names